# The character does not follow the path

Tags: animation, constraints, path

I want the character to follow the path, but its doesnt work...When i click the armature in object mode and add object constraint follow path, the character will move away and doesnt animated as desire.Seek for help

[image]

Comment: Drop us your .blend file.

Comment: hi, thks for help, the blend file is in the  google drive link. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it does follow the path, except that you’re supposed to place the armature at the exact same point as the beginning of the path, to do so just press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, it resets the location at 0/0/0 but as the armature is constrained by the *Follow Path* its new 0/0/0 is the beginning of the curve.

Now second problem, once you’ve reset the location, the armature still goes away. The reason is that you’ve given it an animation as you can see if you open the NLA Editor, and this animation contains location datas that moves it away from the 0/0/0. So either delete this NLA strip or delete the location infos of this action.

To delete the location datas of this action: In the 3D View select the armature, in the NLA select the first NLA strip of the top track (the one that plays), press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to display the action of this strip in the Dopesheet. Go in the Dopesheet, click on the arrow icon button to only see the actions of the selected object, in the left panel unfold the action datas, double click on the *X Location* track and press X to delete this row, same thing with *Y Location* and *Z Location* tracks.

[image]

Comment: Thank for helping, what more question,that is how to delete the location info of this action.Appreciate

Comment: You are really good and i m really appreciate your help. Actually i still have some question. May i ask?

Comment: yes if it's still concerns your main question, otherwise ask another one

Comment: Thank^^ My question is how to i assign the path to the particular action? Like i want to assign the path to the second action( human walking) only in my first NLA strip.

Comment: And i also not sure whether the way that i do animation is correct or not, i am doing my final year project and i m still new to Blender.

Comment: you can't assign a path to a particular action per se, what you can do is control the speed or the stop of the armature along the path for example with the help of the Offset value of the Follow Path constraint, this way you can synchronize actions and Follow Path constraint

Comment: For the"the help of the Offset value of the Follow Path constraint, this way you can synchronize actions and Follow Path constraint". Any tutorial available online?

Comment: maybe try this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsOSDYTsG7o  it explains how to speed up or stop the object along the curve, to synchronize the right action to the right moment, use the NLA

Comment: can add u as friend? just because u really helped me a lot, i really appreciate

Comment: What do you mean? Are there friends in blenderstackexchange?

Comment: maybe facebook?

Comment: Oh ok, actually I prefer to stay anonymous but thanks for the proposition, feel free to ask questions on bse  ;))

Comment: Anyway...thks for help^^

Comment: Ehhhh. in my case, the animation story is the character open the door, then he walk toward sofa and sit down.....i put the open door action and walking action into one NLA strip, isnt correct?but i still dont know how to do the walking follow path

Comment: If your character doesn't walk a long distance maybe don't use follow path, just animate the whole thing?

Comment: actually i want to know, the way i put the actions in one NLA strips is correct or not?

Comment: because this is the first time i do animation and what i know  all learn from youtube

Comment: yes no problem, you can put them in the same track if you don't want any transition, or stack the strips if you need transitions